# Why arent all of my glass windows reflecting the same?

Tags: glass

I'm wondering why my windows dont all reflect the same. In the image you'll see the right 3 windows are much darker than those on the left. As i pan around the scene the left windows reflect the white background, bu the right windows dont appear to, though they do reflect. The left window set are duplicates of the right so left and right should be the same. They certainly have the same materials.

Any clues?

[image: Semi-house]

Comment: Check the normals of the glass pane for inverted geometry.

Comment: Is there a difference between what's behind each window? Is there a room behind one and not behind the other or something?

Comment: OK I'll check the normals, whatever that means. Thanks :o)

Comment: There is a white face backing to every window, set back from the glass by 20mm or something like that. I'll check they're all the same distance.

Comment: Duarte, looks like you were on the money. had to recalc normals. Many thanks.